# When music doesn't Start, Stop button crashing the project

Tags: android, media-player

When I push the next button, I want to go next layout and stop still playing music.
If I push the play button and push the next button app is working.

But, if music doesn't play and I push to the next layout button, the app is crashing because my code try to stopped even though music isn't playing. What can i do ?

```
 package com.gamedom.relaxingmusic;

 import gif.decoder.GifRun;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.SurfaceView;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class Music1 extends Activity {

    public static MediaPlayer mp1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.music1);

        final ImageButton Start1 =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnStart1);
        final ImageButton Stop1 =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnStop1);

        ImageButton SOL1 =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSol1);
        ImageButton SAG1 =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSag1);     

        Stop1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Start1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mp1=MediaPlayer.create(Music1.this, R.raw.firefurnace);
                mp1.start();
                mp1.setLooping(true);

                Start1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Stop1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        Stop1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mp1.stop();
            mp1.release();
            Stop1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Start1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    //////NEXT LAYOUT BUTTON \\\\\\\\\

    SAG1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mp1.isPlaying()) { 
                mp1.stop(); 
            }

            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC2"));

        }
    });

    ////// BACK LAYOUt BUTTON \\\\\\\\\

    SOL1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mp1.isPlaying()) { 
                mp1.stop(); 
            }

             startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC4"));
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is here

```
SOL1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //It try to stoping the music but it's already stopped program is crashes
        if (mp1.isPlaying()) { 
            mp1.stop(); 
        }

        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC4"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any idea where in the code the error is occurring ... any error outputs or trapping in the code that could assist?

Comment: "What can i do ?" - Make sure that your MediaPlayer isn't null before you check if it's playing.

Comment: When I pressed SAG1 button. İt's next layout button. Program is crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you initialize your media player object in an onClick. So, if that event is not fired, your `mp1` variable will be null. I believe you are getting `NullPointerException`.